# UIBarButtonItem with UIButton as CustomView Strange issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I am creating a `UIBarButtonItem` as `rightBarButtonItem` using `itiWithCustomView` method in which `customView` is a `UIButton` with `contentHorizontalAlignment` as `UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight`.
the `barbuttonitem` works fine.
But after a push pop `viewcontroller` operation, the `barbuttonitem` click area is reduced tremendously(I think not more than 3-4 pixels).
Please help me with this issue

```
UIImage *filterImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"filter"]; UIButton *filterButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
filterButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44);
filterButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES; [filterButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"filter"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[filterButton addTarget:self action:@selector(filterTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *filterItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:filterButton];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = filterItem;
```

Comment: Please add at least a snipped code.

Comment: There is entirely too little information here.

Comment: If I add the button in viewDidLoad problem occurs, if I add the code in viewWillAppear then no problem. Any reason for this ambiguous behaviour ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you assigned alignment for moving bar button little bit to right side. Instead of this, you can try following snippet. It might solve your problem.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [self setRightBarButtonWithTarget:self action:@selector(topRightButtonClick) image:@"imagename"];
```

And create common method for create right bar button

```
- (NSArray *)setRightBarButtonWithTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action image:(NSString *)imgName
{
    UIButton *rightBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    rightBtn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [rightBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imgName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightBtn addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    rightBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 26, 26);

    UIBarButtonItem *negativeSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
    negativeSpace.width = -5;
    UIBarButtonItem *homeButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightBtn];

    NSArray *arrBarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:negativeSpace, homeButton, nil];
    return arrBarItems;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful suggestion but see my comment in the question. Your solution not working.